# 2 Deprecations in my Symfony 3 Project

Tags: symfony

I have 2 deprecations in my Symfony 3 project when try to define a custom service in service.yml that I would like to solve but I don't get the way...

[image]

This my code `FollowingExtension.php`

```
 <?php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class FollowingExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine) {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('following', array($this, 'followingFilter'))
        );
    }

    public function followingFilter($user, $followed){
        $following_repo = $this->doctrine->getRepository('BackendBundle:Following');
        $user_following = $following_repo->findOneBy(array(
            "user" => $user,
            "followed" => $followed
        ));

        if(!empty($user_following) && is_object($user_following)){
            $result = true;
        }else{
            $result = false;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'following_extension';
    }
}
```

And this is my `services.yml`:

```
following.twig_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\FollowingExtension
    public: false
    arguments:
        $doctrine: "@doctrine"
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

I would appreciate the help they gave me in trying to solve my problem.

Comment: `getName()` should be deleled.

Answer (score 0):

#### First problem solution

It looks like because of registering services with duplicate name, as declared in your class:

```
`return 'following_extension';`
```

Make sure that you only have one twig service named `following_extension`. If you are sure that only one twig service named `following_extension`, you probably register more than one service using that class.

#### Second problem solution

Replace

```
`use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;`
```

with

```
`use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerInterface;`
```

and also replace

```
`public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine) {`
```

with

```
`public function __construct(ManagerInterface $doctrine) {`
```

Comment: i replaced RegistryInterface by ManagerInterface and get this error message in symfony AutowiringFailedException
Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Twig\FollowingExtension": argument "$doctrine" of method "__construct()" has type "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerInterface" but this class cannot be loaded.

Comment: Try replacing your service config argument with `$doctrine: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"`

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem and i want share the info...

Reading the documentation of Symfony found this [How to Create Service Aliases and Mark Services as Private](https://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container/alias_private.html) and them I declared my service this way:

in  `service.yml:`

```
following.twig_extension: '@AppBundle\Twig\FollowingExtension'
```

and `FollowingExtension.php`

```
    <?php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class FollowingExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    private $managerRegistry;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry) {
        $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
    }

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('following', array($this, 'followingFilter'))
        );
    }

    public function followingFilter($user, $followed){
        $following_repo = $this->managerRegistry->getRepository('BackendBundle:Following');
        $user_following = $following_repo->findOneBy(array(
            "user" => $user,
            "followed" => $followed
        ));

        if(!empty($user_following) && is_object($user_following)){
            $result = true;
        }else{
            $result = false;
        }

        return $result;
    }

}
```

Thanks for helping me and I'm sorry if my english is bad.